# html QNA parser -- Python

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup

I am looking for a solution, which can extract all question and answers pair from any html page. currently I am using regex based functionality but that is not giving me 100% accuracy

```
    
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sitemap_page_source, 'html5lib')
    for elem in soup(text=re.compile(
            r'\s*((?:how|can|what|where|which|describe|who|when|why|should|is|I|Did|do|are|will)[^<>?]*?\s*\?)',
            flags=re.IGNORECASE)):
        # if elem.previous_sibling is None:
        if any(ele in elem for ele in test_list):
            continue
        if "?" in clean_string(elem)[-4:]:
            l.append(elem)
```

Comment: You should try NLTK.

Comment: Want to build a generic or site-specific scraper?